# Obtain the current value of the seed used by the random number generator

Tags: random

I would like to be able to do something like the following pseudocode:

```
SeedRandom[someNumber];  (* Initialize the random number generator's seed for reproducible results *)

Do
    Run a batch of Monte Carlo simulations;
    Obtain the current value of the seed of Mathematica's RNG;
    DumpSave["filename.mx",{monteCarloResults,currentSeedValue}];
Until N batches have run
```

The idea here is that if something goes wrong (Mathematica kernel crashes, etc.), having saved both the results of the simulation and the current seed value of the random number generator's, I wouldn't have to start over and the results would still be fully deterministic/reproducible. I'd just load the seed value from the last file saved, call `SeedRandom[currentSeedValue]`, initialize the loop counter to the value for the next iteration, and go on my merry way.

Does Mathematica have a function that returns the current value of the seed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may get the current state of the random generator with

```
gs = Random`GetRandomState[];
```

This can be loaded back into the generator later with

```
Random`SetRandomState@gs;
```

Then you can continue from where you left off.

Note that these are undocumented functions and as such there is no guarantee that the functionality will remain the same in future versions of Wolfram Language.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: It might also suffice to save and restore the value of `$RandomState`.

Comment: @Daniel, `$RandomState` will only affect the old `Random[type, range]` method, but not the newer `RandomReal[]`/`RandomInteger[]` functions.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less: Oof. How did I not know that? Chagrined am I.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment on Edmund's post, so I shall write here a demonstration of this *undocumented* functionality:

## First session

```
In[1]:= SeedRandom[2019, Method -> "ExtendedCA"];

In[2]:= RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 30]
Out[2]:= {4, -2, 8, 7, -1, 5, -3, -8, 6, -7, -4, 1, 4, 7, -9, -7, 2, -1, -8, -6, 6, -7, 1, 7, 0, 9,
          -1, 4, 7, 9}

In[3]:= Put[Random`GetRandomState[], FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "randstate.m"}]]

In[4]:= RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 10]
Out[4]:= {-5, 7, -7, -2, -2, 6, 1, -8, -4, -4}

In[5]:= Exit[]
```

## Second session

```
In[1]:= Random`SetRandomState[Get[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "randstate.m"}]]]

In[2]:= RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 10]
Out[2]:= {-5, 7, -7, -2, -2, 6, 1, -8, -4, -4}
```

Note that the output of `RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 10]` in both sessions is the same.